# Scan deep directories recursively

Tags: c#, recursion, directory, stack-overflow, .net-4.5

I am using C# 4.5 and I'm trying to scan a fileshare for all folders. I want to skip any folder I cannot access and just continue. What I have done is to do it recursively, this throws a stackoverflow. I understand why this happens. So my question is: are there any work arounds?

How would you implemented this since we cannot use recursive search? Are there any third-party libraries I can use to simplify this? `GetFolder` function is only extracting some information and return a custom class, this works fine.

```
public void GetFoldersFromFS(string filePath)
{
   if (filePath == null)
   {
      return;
   }

   Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(filePath);
   try
   {
       foreach (var directory in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()))
       {
           Resources.Add(GetFolder(new DirectoryInfo(directory)));
           GetFoldersFromFS(directory);
       }
   }
   catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
   {
      Log.Warn(e.Message);
   }
   catch (PathTooLongException e)
   {
      Log.Warn(e.Message);
   }
}
```

Comment: `Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path, "*.*", ` **SearchOption.AllDirectories** `);` ??

Comment: If you want to achieve a stack overflow by a recursive call you need ~ 10.000 iterations. Are you sure that your directory structure is so deep (i don't think that windows supports such a long path name)?

Comment: Yes it is that deep, thas why i also change directories on the way down to avoid the PathTooLongException.

Comment: @L.B: Problem with that is if i have an exception. It just cancels the operation and im left with nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make a list for the directories that you need to do (the to-do-list).
2. Initially, add the single directory (on the share) to the to-do-list.
3. Take the first directory from the list and scan it.
4. When you scan a directory, add any subdirectories to the to-do-list (at the end of the list).
5. Go back to 3 until the to-do-list is empty.

Voila, scanning without recursion.

Pseudo code (without any try-catch):

```
public List<string> ScanDirectory(string directory) {
    var toDoList = new Queue<string>();
    var result = new List<string>();
    toDoList.Enqueue(directory);

    // Keep going while there is anything to do
    while (toDoList.Count > 0) {
        // Get next directory-to-scan, and add it to the result
        var currentDir = toDoList.Dequeue();
        result.Add(currentDir);
        // Get sub directories
        var subDirectories = new DirectoryInfo(currentDir).GetDirectories();    // TODO: Add any other criteria you want to check
        // Add the sub directories to the to-do list
        foreach (var subDirectory in subDirectories) {
            toDoList.Enqueue(subDirectory);
        }
    }

    // Return all found directories
    return result;
}
```

Comment: If you're keeping a `List` to return, you might as well use it as your to-do queue as well - e.g. keep a current index and return when it exceeds the length of the list.

Comment: True. It was just a quick example. I think this shows better what the intention is though.

Comment: It does seem to be working :) Quit simple solution, feel abit stupid now. haha, anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of handling the exception you could check if you have rights to access that folder via the [ACL of the Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1h6d4k4.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Your recursive call to GetFoldersFromFS() is wrong. It keeps passing the same folder to the recursive call!

Also, you should NOT be calling Directory.SetCurrentDirectory() or GetCurrentDirectory().

Instead, at your recursive call just do: GetFoldersFromFS(directory):

```
   foreach (var directory in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(filePath))
   {
       Resources.Add(GetFolder(new DirectoryInfo(directory)));
       GetFoldersFromFS(directory);
   }
```

Comment: Indeed that is true, was a typo.